# 2 column grid layout with masonry

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-masonry

I am trying to build a 2 column grid layout with [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/), but when I try using masonry they layout turns into this one column grid.

I think I may be using it wrong. I have been reading through the documentation, but don't know what else to do? To me, it seems like this code should cause they layout I am trying to achieve.

Here is the layout I am trying to achieve:
[image: Layout I am trying to achieve]

Here is my page with masonry: https://googledrive.com/host/0BwJVaMrY8QdcVDBweWk2UXlfTVE/KE%20copy.html

And here is the page without masonry: https://googledrive.com/host/0BwJVaMrY8QdcVDBweWk2UXlfTVE/KE.html

All I am trying to do is bring that first column up.

I would greatly appreciate any and all help!

Comment: At the front page it says: "All options are optional, but columnWidth and itemSelector are recommended.", but I don't see columnWidth in your js... try adding it.

Comment: @drip Now all the items are top aligned to the top corner of the container. The even items are shifted to the right some though, like having a small left margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I download the html and tested it.

Please remove the margin-left of the items.

```
.dataCard { margin-left:3.2%; } /*Without this*/
```

And start the mansonary like so:

```
$('#main').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.dataCard',
    gutter: 20
});
```

This were the only changes done.

Here is an image of the result.
[image: Screen of the page]